# MongoDB - NodeJS update array element at specifix index set dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem updating my collection based on an index that i create dynamically. What i am trying to do is update my milestones array with the following code:

```
var query1 = 'milestones.'+data.next_milestone+'.actual_date';
var query2='milestones.'+data.next_milestone+'.submitted';
var query3= 'milestones.'+data.next_milestone+'.comment' ;
        Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,
          {$set:
          {
            query1 : new Date(req.body.date),
            query2 : true,
            query3 : req.body.comment,
          "next_milestone" : data.next_milestone+0
        }}).then((data)=>{
                  res.status(200).send();
              })
```

I tested the query strings and they all result in correct string, example :

```
milestones.1.comment
```

But my collection is not updated, the next milestone part is working i set there 0 to prevent it from updating while testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the milestone to update by its ID can use mongo $ operator identifies to update the milestone/object inside the array

```
Project.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id, "milestones._id": <your_milestone_id> },
     { $set: { "milestones.$.comment" : 666 } },function(err,doc){

     });
```

See details here:
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

If want to add a new milestone use mongo push instead:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/